# Where to start to learn OpenGL

Tags: opengl, embedded

As OpenGL evolves, it seems that there are three camps:

- OpenGL legacy, packed with "deprecated APIs"
- OpenGL ES, for embedded systems
- OpenGL "new stuff" which comes out every couple of months.

If I wanted to learn OpenGL for modern systems, where should I start?   And most importantly, is there a reason to go beyond OpenGL ES for someone that has never done OpenGL before?

Comment: This seems like a SO question...or [game development](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2825/game-development) I'm voting to close, this is offtopic.

Comment: [meta discussion](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40/opengl-question-offtopic).

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-open-gl

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the NeHe opengl tutorials:  http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Comment: The NeHe tutorials do not teach modern OpenGL. They are mostly out of date, and shouldn't really be recommended to an OpenGL newbie.